# how to convert base10 decimal (big endian) to binary ( a hex in little endian) in a char array

Tags: c, hex, decimal, endianness

I'm having some trouble in iOS.
I have been trying to convert a base10 decimal value into a *little endian*, *hexadecimal* string.

So far I am unable to do so.

For example I would like to convert the following integer in *little endian* hexadecinmal:

> int val = 11234567890123456789112345678911;

Comment: That value wont fit in an integer. (either a signed 32 bit integer or unsigned 32 bit integer)

Comment: It also has no base or endianness. It's just a value.

Comment: hmm... I found something similar to what I want in python, though nit sure how to convert it to C or objective C:
>>> n = int("11234567890123456789112345678911", 10)
>>> out = []
>>> for i in range(32):
...   out.append(n & 0xff)
...   n >>= 8
... 
>>> ''.join([chr(x) for x in out]).encode('hex')

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void MulBytesBy10(unsigned char* buf, size_t cnt)
{
  unsigned carry = 0;
  while (cnt--)
  {
    carry += 10 * *buf;
    *buf++ = carry & 0xFF;
    carry >>= 8;
  }
}

void AddDigitToBytes(unsigned char* buf, size_t cnt, unsigned char digit)
{
  unsigned carry = digit;
  while (cnt-- && carry)
  {
    carry += *buf;
    *buf++ = carry & 0xFF;
    carry >>= 8;
  }
}

void DecimalIntegerStringToBytes(unsigned char* buf, size_t cnt, const char* str)
{
  memset(buf, 0, cnt);

  while (*str != '\0')
  {
    MulBytesBy10(buf, cnt);
    AddDigitToBytes(buf, cnt, *str++ - '0');
  }
}

void PrintBytesHex(const unsigned char* buf, size_t cnt)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    printf("%02X", buf[cnt - 1 - i]);
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char buf[16];

  DecimalIntegerStringToBytes(buf, sizeof buf, "11234567890123456789112345678911");

  PrintBytesHex(buf, sizeof buf); puts("");

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/x7ydGr)):

```
0000008DCCD8BFC66318148CD6ED543F
```

Converting the resulting bytes into a hex string (if that's what you want) should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You can't. This number would require a 128 bits integer.

Answer (score 0):

Other problems aside (that have already been pointed out by others so I won't repeat), if you do ever need to swap endianness - say you are doing something cross platform (or working with audio sample formats for another example) where it matters to do so, there are some functions provided by Core Foundation, such as `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()`.

For more information on those functions check out the [Byte-Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html) pages, and you may find what you are looking for.

Comment: Other problems aside, the OP actually needs to get a little endian hexadecimal string representation of the int value.