# PHP Convert Big Endian to Hex

Tags: php, endianness

I am trying to write a PHP script where I can take a big endian packet and convert it over to hex. I understand you can use unpack if anyone can explain the steps I greatly appreciate it. I was told I needed to flip the bits and add one but I do not know if unpack already does that or how to do it. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556572/how-to-convert-base10-decimal-big-endian-to-binary-a-hex-in-little-endian-i

Comment: Data of what data type? Integer? UTF-x string?

Comment: This is taken out of the documentation for the message structure. Messages passed between an application and the interface have the same basic packet structure. This
structure consists of a 20 byte IP Header, an 8 byte UDP header, the header and the message.

Note that all bytes in multi-byte fields are transmitted in Net Endian format (Big Endian) where the most significant
bits are transmitted first. For example, for a 32-bit field, bits 31-24 are transmitted first, 16-23 second, 8-15 third
and 0-7 last

Answer (score 0):

Depending on data length (and type), you should use [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) with relevant arguments
n - 16 bit
N - 32 bit

Then you pack() it to hex with H or h as arguments